# Audio Queued Not immediate playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I am working on an Audio related file in html5.

I used following function to change the audio

```
function Audioplay(id) {
    var id=id.split('Symbols')[1];
    var FolderRedirect=id.split('')[0];

    $("#audio").get(0).pause();
    $("#audio").attr('src',  ' ');
    $("#audio").attr('src', 'assets/audio/'+Folder[FolderRedirect]+'/sound_'+id+'.mp3');
    $("#audio").get(0).play();
};
```

It changes the audio, but it will be played completely the first time. How can I play it immediately `onclick`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your function, you're calling `play()` as the last line. Remove it, and instead add it as a click handler on whatever element you're using as a control.

There are other cleanups you should consider:

- Function names conventionally begin with a lowercase letter--functions beginning with an uppercase letter imply that you should use the `new` operator to create one.
- You redeclare `id` as a local variable, even though it is passed in as an argument.
- You reference the variable `Folder` from within the body of your function. That makes it hard to reason about what is happening there. Consider either passing the `folder` array (note the correct case) into the function as an argument, or even better, separating the derivation of your redirect into a separate function.
- You force jQuery to find the `#audio` element 4 times. Instead, store it in a local variable so jQuery only has to look it up once.

A reworked function:

```
function playAudio($audio) {
  $audio.get(0).play();
}

function normalizeId(rawId) {
  var idParts = id.split('Symbols');
  return idParts[1];
}

function getFolderRedirectFromNormalizedId(normalizedId) {
  return normalizedId.split('')[0];
}

function getSourcePathFromId(id) {
  var folders, folderRedirect, normalizedId;
  folders = [/* Initialize your folder array */];

  normalizedId = normalizeId(id);

  folderRedirect = getFolderRedirectFromNormalizedId(normalizedId);

  return 'assets/audio/' + folders[folderRedirect] + '/sound_' + normalizedId + '.mp3';
}

function initializeAudio(id) {
  var src, $audio;
  $audio = $("#audio");
  $audio.get(0).pause();
  $audio.attr('src',  ' ');

  src = getSourcePathFromId(id);
  $audio.attr('src', src);

  $('.control-you-want-to-click').click(function() {
    playAudio($audio);
  });
}

initializeAudio();
```